# QueryString does not properly parse or (or create) arrays like https://example.com/?computer[desktop]=Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var u2 = new Url("https://example.com/");
u2.query["computer"] = {};
u2.query["computer"]["desktop"] = "Mac";
alert(u2);
```

The result should be this: `https://example.com/?computer[desktop]=Mac`

Instead, I get this: `https://example.com/?computer=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Also, when I parse a URL that looks like: `https://example.com/?computer[desktop]=Mac`

Inspecting the object in the console should look like return something like:

```
Computer: Object
desktop: "Mac"
```

Instead I get this: `computer[desktop]: "Mac"`

"desktop" isn't recognized as an object inside of "computer". "computer[desktop]" is simply used as the key like any other string.

https://github.com/Mikhus/domurl/

Answer (score 0):

It is not parsing it wrong. And `Url()` seems to decide to parse the query string as 
[*`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) data. Where the left side of a `=` is the name of the field and the right is the value, and each of those pairs separated by `&`

The query string is imply just that a null value or ASCII string. There is no set standard on what the format ***MUST*** be or how to parse it. That is left up to the frameworks being used.

If you want it in a particular format, or parsed in a particular way, you will have to do so yourself or work with how that framework decides to use it.

So in your case using Url you would have to use the string `computer[desktop]` as a key to correctly set the query string the way you want it

```
u2.query['computer[desktop]'] = "Mac"
```

Comment: Your approach creates a new object "computer[desktop]" separate from "computer."

Comment: It's not a new object, it's a property that contains a string value on the query object, which is what domurl's Url expects. As i stated in the answer if you want to use your approach you will have to implement your own formatting / parsing or use a different library that does it as that is not what domurl's Url class does.